# Default values in Insert Select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

How to pass default values in the Insert Select construction in SQL?

I have a table:

```
    create table1 (field1 int, field2 int, field3 int default 1337)
    create table2 (field1 int, field2 int)
```

I want to insert `table2` into `table1` with a construction similar to this:

```
    insert into table1 select field1, field2, DEFAULT from table2
```

Is it possible to use something instead of `DEFAULT` in my example to get the task done? How are previously selected tables usually inserted with default values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table2
```

I tested this using SQL Server 2005

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(
        field1 INT,
        field2 INT,
        field3 INT DEFAULT 1337
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (field1,field2,field3) SELECT 1, 2, 3

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
        field1 INT,
        field2 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table2 (field1,field2) SELECT 15, 16

INSERT INTO @Table1 (field1,field2)
SELECT  field1,
        field2
FROM    @Table2

SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

Comment: @Alec, have a look at the example in my answer.

Comment: @astander: Yep, it came out it works. I first tried it with 'values'. @Don: There should be no 'values' with select, 'values' is followed by the actual values in parenthesis rather that select :)